# C conditional compilation - is there a more elegant way

Tags: c, compilation, conditional-compilation

I am refactoring a few c code files based on a variable set in Makefile, and I realize that there are lots of code that need conditional compilation across the files. I find that I'm doing this a lot:

```
#if COND1
void func1(int a1, int b1) {
   Struct1 info;
#else
void func1(int a1) {
   Struct2 info;
#endif
   switch (info.type)
   {
#if COND1
    case c1:
    case c2:
...
#else
    case c3:
#endif
    case c4:
...
    }
```

The code soon becomes messy and ugly in my opinion.
But the portion of the code that needs conditional compilation is like 10%-20% and all the others are exactly the same, so I don't think I need extra files just to distinguish between the two versions of the code.
Is there any way I can do this more elegantly? Inserting #if... everywhere in the code makes it a headache just to read. I'm quite new to C so please let me know if there's anything I need to catch up on and any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The plague of conditional compilation can be altered by compiling `#if COND1` / …all of `func1` with the 2-argument version … / `#else` / …all of `func1` with the 1-argument version… / `#endif`. However, even that's not great — you have two different functions with the same name and different argument lists, so the calls will also be conditional. I would call the functions by two different names and get on with life from there. You might be able to use a number of small functions to provide the common functionality between the two implementations. IMO, renaming will be clearer in the long run.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `makefile`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet in my case the conditions are defined in makefile, so I suppose people who are familiar with makefile might have run into the same issue before - it's just my assumption but please let me know if it's not appropriate and it'd be nice to let me know the reason why, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, but what if `COND1` depends on something like the OS version or the version of the software that this c program depends on, and there are other programs that expect to call `func1` by exactly the name "func1" and I can't change anything about the other programs?

Comment: @instant501 Well, your question is not about Makefiles, so tagging it with `makefile` is misleading. I suggest to remove it.

Comment: If some programs expect to call `func1()` with one argument and others expect to call `func1()` with two arguments, those programs must link with separate builds of the library.  Those libraries must either be stored in different locations or given different names in a single directory.  However, under those circumstances, you'll not rename the function (though I'd argue that it was probably a mistake to change the interface between releases — the new variant should have been given a new name when it was created). I'd still aim to have the two implementations separate rather than interleaved.

Comment: I note that you'll also need different headers — one declaring the one-argument variant and the other the two-argument variant.  And the code being compiled to use this functionality will need to know which header to include.  Or you'll have the `#ifdef COND1` code in the header.  I still think there is probably a failure to identify the correct abstractions — you are making life complicated for yourself and your users.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid many conditional compilation directives, you could use this approach with macros:

```
#if COND1
#define Func1Struct  Struct1
#else
#define Func1Struct  Struct2
#define func1(a, b)  (func1)(a)
#endif


void func1(int a1, int b1) {
   Func1Struct info;
...
```

The advantage of defining `func1` as a macro is you only have a single definition point for the function, which is better for ctags and debugging and the call sites are handled transparently too.

Platform specific `case` values still require explicit preprocessor directives.

This is not *elegant* by any means, but it does hide some of the ugliness effectively.